# Как организовать проверку на одинаковые элементы и вывести сообщение, если они есть?

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 10, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10 }, i, j,k;
int(*b)[5];
b = (int(*)[5])a;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        cout << b[i][j] << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Посмотрите на [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Comment: @Xeller, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Все ответы плохие, кроме совета, данного avp. Я хочу уточнить только, что если задание понимать буквально, т.е. надо определить лишь сам факт наличия повторяющихся элементов, то можно еще вот так извратиться:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 10, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10 };
    int repetitions = 0;

    int compare(const void* pa, const void* pb)
    {
        int a = *(int*)pa;
        int b = *(int*)pb;
        if (a == b)
        {
            repetitions = 1;
            return 0;
        }
        return a < b ? -1 : 1;
    }

    qsort(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(int), sizeof(int), compare);
    puts(repetitions ? "Yes!" : "No.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Боюсь ваш пример не работает http://ideone.com/05Lyzr

Comment: Хитро придумано. 

Если уж извращаться, то можно взглянуть и на такую модификацию:

    main () {
     ...
     sigjmp_buf jmp;
     void *L = &&L1;
     ...
     if (sigsetjmp(jmp, 0))
       goto *L;

     int compare(const void* pa, const void* pb) {
        int a = *(int*)pa;
        int b = *(int*)pb;
        if (a == b) {
           repetitions = 1;
           siglongjmp(jmp);
        }
        return a < b ? -1 : 1;
     }
     qsort(...);
     L1:;
     puts(...);
     ...

Жаль, нелокальный goto (по void \*L) не позволяет корректно выходить из функций, а то можно было бы ...

Comment: @inceon, вложенные функции (и адреса меток) это расширение gcc.

Это Си, а не C++. В нем все работает.

Comment: Для того, чтобы прекратить сортировку вовремя, я бы просто написал ее код. Например, гномья сортировка столь лаконична, что получится едва ли не короче, чем вызывать стандартный qsort с этим вашим longjump.

Comment: Правда есть разница в скорости работы (IMHO для сотни миллионов чисел разница будет измеряться часами).

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется в виду одинаковые элементы в массиве, то

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<20;j++){
        if(a[i]==a[j]){
            cout << "Identical elements: " << i << " and " << j << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Или

```
#include <algorithm>
...
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    if(count(a,a+20,a[i])>1){
        cout << "There identical " << a[i] << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 10, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10 };
    vector<int> v(a, a + 20); // закинули массив в вектор
    set<int> s; // сюда мы будем ложить повторяющие числа в массиве и хранить их в единственном числе (искомый результат)

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){ // берем число из массива
        if(count(v.begin(), v.end(), *it) > 1){ // если есть дублирующее значение
                cout << "finded: " << *it << endl; // отладка
                s.insert(*it); // ложим его в неповторяющийся контейнер типа set
                continue;
            }

    }

    for (set<int>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++){ // вывод результата
        cout << "Look for duplicate value: -> " << *it << " <- found: " << count(v.begin(), v.end(), *it) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

[image]